# ABPersonViewController - callback from "Edit" button - objective C

Tags: objective-c, iphone, addressbook, abaddressbook

I am using ABPersonViewController and adding a label on the "Info" view.
The thing is:
when I click the "Edit" button, since the : personController.allowsEditing = YES;
my view goes to the "edit view" and my Label is still there (not as I planed )
I am trying to figure out if I can be "notify" when the user pressed the "Edit" button , so I can remove my label from the current view before it goes to the "Edity View"

The only option I am thinking about  is  to disable editing in ABPersonViewController and to create an "Edit" button of my own, then I will have to try and implement the same behavior of the Addressbook "Edit" button ...

Is there an option for a callback , when the "Edit" button is pressed ? and still keep the same behavior of the ABPersonViewController?

or maybe there is a way to know on which view I am in (tag or somthing ... ?) in the ABPersonViewController so I can remove the label when I am not on the "Info" view

Thanks

Itay

Comment: What programming/scripting language? Please edit your question and update tags accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you can subclass and override `setEditing:animated`. This setter is invoked for both `Edit` and `Done` but not for `Cancel` and a callback is still required. The example below hides the toolbar when editing the record and restores it when done.

```
// Override setter to show/hide toolbar
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = editing;
    if (editing) {
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTarget:self];
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setAction:@selector(cancel)];
    }
}

// Cancel button callback (does not invoke setEditing:animated)
- (void)cancel {
    [self setEditing:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Subclassing ABPersonViewController is not currently allowed by Apple.

Answer (score 2):

Just figured out a slightly hacky looking way to get notified when edit is pressed.

create a subclass of `ABPersonViewController` and attach your own custom action to the edit button: In the initialization for your view controller:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTarget:self];
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setAction:@selector(editPressed)];

}
```

I couldn't find a better reference to the edit button than: `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem`

then create your `editPressed` action:

```
-(void)editPressed{

    [super setEditing:!super.editing];

    if(self.editing){

       NSLog(@"Editing");

       //Insert code to put your custom view in edit mode

    }else{

       NSLog(@"Not editing");

      //Insert code to take your custom view out of edit mode

    }
}
```

It's important to call `[super setEditing:!super.editing]` first as this makes the `UIPersonViewController` go in and out of edit mode as appropriate (Defining your custom action overwrites the default action). It also properly updates the the '`editing`' property of your view controller so that '`self.editing`' gives the correct value.

Comment: pressing "Done" (righttabbarbutton) is causing crash with this solution..any comments?